# Web scraping interest rate tables with svg elements

Tags: web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape the coin-name and rates from a section. The elements for coin-name is a not a string but svg, which is fine, and we can scrape the img src. The problem is, we can't target the right selector to scrape the right img src from the "Our Interest Rates" section. I am using simplescraper.io.

Page to scrape: https://why.blockchain.com/interest

Comment: The expected output would be:
BTC, 4%, $300 Minimum
ETH, 5%, $100 Minimum
BCH, 6%, $1 Minimum
XLM, 6%, $1 Minimum
USDT, 13.5%, $100 Minimum
PAX, 13.5%, $100 Minimum

Answer (score 1):

> **Here you go**

```
from xrzz import http
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = 'https://why.blockchain.com/interest'

req = http("get", url=url,headers={
                  "Host": 'why.blockchain.com',
                  "Connection": "Close",
                  "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; SM-J400F) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.66 Mobile Safari/537.36"
      }, tls=True).body()

data = bs(req.decode(), 'lxml').select("#page-block-79549idxanq > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1)")
for i in b:
    perc = [pr.text for pr in i.find_all('span', class_="x_545fe640")]
    mini = [mi.text for mi in i.find_all('span', class_="x_38b70452") if mi.text.startswith("$")]
    cryp = ["BTC", "ETH", "BCH", "XLM", "USDT", "PAX"]
    for x, y, z in zip(cryp, perc, mini):
        print(f"{x},{y},{z}", end=", ")
```

---

> [**OUTPUT**](https://res.cloudinary.com/drleuqqfh/image/upload/v1622292747/Scrap.jpg)

Comment: Thanks mate, this is good except that the coin names and the order are hardcoded in your script. The coin list can change and so can the order.